# I can't connect directly to SQL using local IP if router has port forward enabled

Tags: sql-server, port-forwarding

I'm experiencing a rather weird situation. I have a SQL server that I connect every timd by using this "Connection String":

```
 Data Source=TCP:MyPublic-IP\SQLEXPRESS, 1433; 
 Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; 
 User ID=MyUser; 
 Password=MyPassword;
```

I have "Port Forward" enabled in my router as follow:

```
 Inside -> Start port = 1433, End port =1433
 Outside -> Start port = 1433, End port = 1433
 Server = 192.168.0.185
```

This config works all the time, but the weird part is that I CANNOT connect from a local computer directly to the server if the Router has "Port Forward" enabled, for example:

```
 Data Source=TCP:192.168.0.185\SQLEXPRESS, 1433;
```

As soon as I disable the port forward or change the SQL server IP address then I can connect again from a local computer using the local IP instead of the Public IP.

Anybody has a thought on what's happening in the background that results in this behavior?.

Comment: Sounds like a NAT issue on the router. You can use `curl` commands to test connectivity on the port: `curl -v telnet://192.168.0.185:1433`

Comment: What's the make & model of the router? Usually port-forwarding has no effect on LAN traffic so yeah, this is odd.

Comment: The make and model is NetGear Docsis 3

Comment: So it's a combo cable-modem + router then..?

Comment: @SamAndrew81 yes, it's a combo